# what is exact difference between activity_main.xml and content_main.xml in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

In an  updated version of android studio, it create 2 `files` automatically, I read about these files , but am still confused, as both work similarly, So how to decide which one should I use to put the things and code, what are the things I should put in these 2 files ?

Comment: also where should i put my stuffs such as button, textview, all these things for my app..

Comment: Please do some basic research before posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880722/what-is-the-role-of-content-main-xml-in-android-studio-1-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183107/difference-between-content-main-xml-and-activity-main-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414034/why-is-there-content-main-xml-and-activity-main-xml-by-default-instead-of-just-a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190072/content-main-xml-vs-activity-main-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331119/what-to-use-activity-main-or-content-main http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684318/

Answer (score 4):

This is just a cool concept , where by `content_main.xml` layout is just included inside the `activity_main.xml`. So you have to put your stuff in `content_main.xml`.

The essence of using `activity_main.xml` is to insert other widgets such as (Floating Action Bar ) on top of a `content_main.xml` layout.

There for basically , this approach just teaches us on how to include an `xml` file into the others , instead of congesting several components in **one** `xml` file.

***All in all, you just edit your `content_main.xml` layout***